# iOS changing background color with delay (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delay, background-color

I want to set the view's background color and change it to another color after a certain delay. Here is how I tried it:

```
print("setting color 1")
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFF0000)
print("sleeping")
sleep(3)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFFFF00)
print("setting color 2")
```

However, I don't get the first color. The app stays at its initial color, waits for 3 seconds and changes than to color 2. No sign of color 1. How to fix that?

`sleep(3)` seems to lock the view from updating its color. However, if I call `myButton.isEnabled = false` and set it after the delay back to `true`, the button behaves as expected and stays disable during the delay.

Comment: `Dispatch.main.asyncAfter`  try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFF0000)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3.0 ) {

  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFFFF00)

}
```

Comment: Error: '+' is not a postfix unary operator

Comment: @black You need to separate the `+` from the rest with a space (` `). Postfix operators are more advanced operators you don't need to know for now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem solved by using Timer. just paste the code inside viewDidLoad function.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(change), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Following function inside your class

```
@objc func change() {
  view.backgroundColor = .black  //change your color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this function (can be used whenever you want):

```
// MARK: Create delay
func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

Then to create the effect you want, do:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFF0000) // Display red

delay(3) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFFFF00) // Display yellow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for swift 5

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFF0000)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { [weak self] in
    self?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( rgb: 0xFFFF00)
}
```